# Bug at my vector implementation

Tags: c++, vector

I'm implementing a vector (using the allocator class).

```
explicit vector() : Capacity(0), Size(0) // first constructor
{
    buffer = Free = End;
}
explicit vector(size_t sz, const T& initial = T()) // second constructor 
{
    Capacity = sz;
    Size = sz;
    buffer = alloc.allocate(sz);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    {
        alloc.construct(buffer+i, initial);
    }
}
template<typename Iterator>
vector(Iterator beg, Iterator lst) // third constructor
{
    std::ptrdiff_t sz(lst - beg);
    buffer = alloc.allocate(sz);
    Iterator index(beg);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    {
        alloc.construct(buffer+i, *index++);
    }
    Size = sz;
    Capacity = sz;
}
vector(const vector<T> &rhs)
{
    *this = vector<T>(rhs.begin(), rhs.end());
}

/* .... */

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec1(10, 5);
    vector<int> vec2(vec1.begin(), vec1.end());
    /* .... */
}
```

Here are the constructors I have defined. When I use third constructor, I get the error message:

```
test.cpp:11:41: error: invalid conversion from ‘vector<int>::iterator {aka int*}’ to ‘long unsigned int’ [-fpermissive]
```

I have come to the conclusion that the compiler confuses the second constructor with the third, as they both have two arguments. What can I do?

Comment: `std::ptrdiff_t sz(lst - beg)` --> will not work unless `Iterator` is a pointer type (I know, it can be made to work but that's not the point), in which case why is the constructor templated?

Comment: Out of interest, why are you implementing a vector? Presumably this is a purely academic excercise?

Comment: "When I use third constructor" --- where? Show the code.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out how the real stl vector works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard vector solves it by having a special `iterator` class inside itself, and uses that as arguments. This means that while there is the same number of arguments, the types of the arguments will be different.

Comment: I have searched a bit the subject and I have found that the `iterator` use in the constructor is a template type: `template<class InputIterator> vector(InputIterator beg, InputIterator end)`